# The operator % is undefined for the argument type(s) Random, int

Tags: java

I was trying to code the random string array but I've got an error what I tell you in this question title.

```
else if(message.contains("명언"))
{
    System.out.println("심심이:" + sok[random%12]);  // I've got an error in this code
}
```

Comment: To answer this question one would need to know what datatype `random` is.

Comment: what error you get?

Comment: If your object `random` is type `java.util.Random`, then maybe you need `sok[random.nextInt()%12]`

Answer (score 2):

You need to read a value from random.

```
sok[random.nextInt()%12]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a random function with a value 0.0 - 1.0, but one would need to multiply by 12, take the int value and do modulo 12.

However the Random class can do:

```
Random random = new Random();
System.out.println("심심이:" + sok[random.nextInt(12)]);
```

This yields a value 0, 1, 2, ... 11.